# Correctly understanding truth table problem?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I'm typing up a solution set for an "intro to proof" course. One of the problems asks the student to "construct a truth table for $(P \implies Q) \implies (\neg P)$." I interpreted this as requesting this table:

$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c||c|}
\hline
P & Q & P \implies Q & \neg P & (P \implies Q) \implies \neg P \\ \hline
T & T & T & F & F \\ 
T & F & F & F & T \\ 
F & T & T & T & T \\ 
F & F & T & T & T \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

I'm embarrassed, but: is this the right interpretation of the question?

Comment: For future reference, Stack Exchange (i.e. Mathjax) supports the array environment but not the tabular environment.

Comment: Strictly speaking, probably not. The truth table in this case would be the first two columns and the last. The other columns show the work in producing the truth table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that looks exactly right.